# PHP behaving strange when printing form

Tags: php, jquery, html, forms

So I'm running this:

```
if($results) 
{
    foreach ( $results as $booking ) 
    {
        echo '<tr><form id="form'.$booking->b_id.'"><td>'.$booking->name.'</td><td>'.$booking->date.'</td></tr></form>';
    }
}
```

For some reason when I try to pull the form data with jQuery it's empty, when I check the markup in the Chrome devtools it looks like this:

```
<tr><form id="form6"></form><td>test</td><td>2015-09-17</td></tr>
```

As you can see the form is printed before anything else. I just don't get why, I'm probably missing something pretty basic here.

Does anyone have a clue?

Comment: You can't wrap part of table in a `form`. This is the clue.

Comment: If you want `<form> <table></table> </form>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't wrap part of table in a `form`, it's illegal, so browser rebuilds your incorrect html.

You can either:

```
<form>
   <table><!-- Your table here --></table>
</form>
```

Or place a form in a single `td`:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><form><!-- One form --></form></td>
        <td><form><!-- Another form --></form></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: For copmpletness, could you place a form wrapped around a table row, like `<table><form><tr>...</tr></form><tr>...</tr></table>`?

Comment: Thanks alot for the quick and clear answer, I obviously need to read up on that! :)